# Open source web grid control with copy/paste support to excel spreadsheets

Tags: datagrid

I am looking for a web datagrid control to integrate in ASP.NET app.
The most important feature required is the ability to copy-paste from and to excel spreadsheet right from the grid on the web page.

Other than Google spreadsheets I found this product ( not open source ) - http://www.editgrid.com/ 
looks like the closest match to my requirement but is not open source.

Answer (score 1):

try taking a look at the [extjs extensions](http://www.codeplex.com/ExtJsExtenderControl) on codeplex